# Where to place facebook_connect files in my app?

Tags: django, django-facebook

I have used **facebook friends app** for inviting friends in my app. So I want know to that where I have to place its files in my app because it has  *mode, view manager, admin, setting, url and template files.*

I am not sure  but may be by just keep the whole app inside project works !!!!    But it doesn't work for me that's why I ask this **question.**

Here is the Github project for it: https://github.com/barszczmm/django-easy-friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the facebook friends app? can you supply a link? normally the best way to install apps is to set up a virtual environment (http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) and then installl your app in there (along with Django and everything else you need)

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv python-pip
virtualenv django-env
./django-env/bin/activate
pip install Django
pip install -e git://github.com/barszczmm/django-easy-friends.git#egg=django-easy-friends
# follow the instructions in the django-easy-friends docs
```